# Code in a question was changed after getting suggestions via answers and/or comments?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-invalidation

Today, I saw [a question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/my-early-stage-statistics-homework-assistant) that asked to review the OP's code. On reading the answers, I found that they repeat or just explain the things seen in the code and say:

> You can use xxx instead of yyy

when the OP's code clearly uses xxx. On closer inspection, I found out that the OP had modified the code taking the suggestions given into consideration.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: Nope. That invalidates the answers and should be rollbacked.

Comment: I can't seem to find the 'rollback' button. I was talking about [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/my-early-stage-statistics-homework-assistant). I posted this because another user [told that it need not be rollbacked](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94060/inserting-filename-reading-data-inserting-regex-and-testing-if-each-line-matc#comment171501_94060)

Comment: For comments it is acceptable, for answers it is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/52915)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying the question to incorporate suggestions from answers is called [answer-invalidation](/questions/tagged/answer-invalidation).  Doing that on any Stack Exchange site is considered to be an abuse of editing privileges.

In addition, [Code Review also forbids appending improved versions of the code to the question](/help/someone-answers), to prevent confusion about what is being asked.

Our standard response to these incidents is to roll back to a previous version and [inform the original poster that such edits are forbidden](/a/4954/9357).  I have done that on this question.  Thank you for raising the issue.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I can't seem to find the rollback button. Does it appear once I have sufficient rep?

Comment: Click on "edited _n_ hours ago" to view the history. When you have earned editing privileges, you will see the option to rollback to any previous version.